# Telling cUrl not to normalize a url

Tags: url, curl

When using curl to call some url, it simplifies the path in the url (for example from `/a/../b` to `/b`). How can I tell cUrl not to do so?

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

$ curl -v 'localhost/a/../b'
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost/b
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pass the `--path-as-is` flag:

```
$ curl --path-as-is 'http://localhost/a/../b'
```

Comment: `curl: option --path-as-is: is unknown` - curl 7.35.0, do you know which curl version added this?

Comment: @estani according to the man page: "Aded (sic) in 7.42.0"

Comment: At least now a days none uses such an older version anymore, so the answer is for all purposes right

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling to find a way to test my server's defence against traversal attacks. The server is http/2-only, which makes all REST clients unusable. Browsers like Chrome evaluate the URL before sending the request so that's no good. Fortunately `curl` saves the day, yet again.