# Tell Firefox not to normalize a URL

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to disable URL normalization in Firefox?

Similar to [this answer for cUrl](https://superuser.com/questions/1025282/telling-curl-not-to-normalize-a-url), I'm looking for a way to disable temporarily the way Firefox will, for example turn `www.example.com/../../../foo/file.txt` into `www.example.com/foo/file.txt`.

Like other modern browsers, Firefox follows the specs:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.

I browsed through about:config and searched for extensions but had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not on a firefox machine at the moment so I can't test, but I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is to set `browser.fixup.alternative.enabled` to false.

EDIT: Oops! I missed you saying you browser `about:config` already. Sorry!

Comment: If the setting accomplishes what the OP is looking for, it's a perfectly valid answer. You could improve on this answer by incorporating a description of what this setting does. If you feel that your answer is not a good answer to the question for some reason, then I suggest deleting it.

Comment: Thank you. I've not spent too much time posting here.
It was sourced from [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.), where they also explain what it does - second-guess the user on url input.

Comment: This is a very useful setting to know about but did not keep the URL intact as entered.  I hope you don't delete the comment.